# Making Table of Contents Webpart Relative to Site

Tags: web-part, page-layout

I'm creating a sidebar navigation in a Page Layout and one of the items I'd like is a Table of Contents. I got it to work and it's showing the navigation links, however I have to set it up for each page.

I'd like to set up the web part inside the page layout to automatically default to the current site's navigation, not the Site Collection's navigation. What am I doing wrong here? Is there some handy variable like ($weburl)? Maybe something with the checkbox of "Show content from starting location"?